# Please explain this snippet of haml code/documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
%div{:class => [@item.type, @item == @sortcol && [:sort, @sortdir]] } Contents
```

could render as any of:

```
<div class="numeric sort ascending">Contents</div>
<div class="numeric">Contents</div>
<div class="sort descending">Contents</div>
<div>Contents</div>
```

I don't really understand the `@sortcol && [:sort, @sortdir]` part of this snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This relies on operator precedence. So it is evaluated like this:

1. `@item == @sortcol` is either true or false.

   - when `false`

     1. `&&` returns `false` because the other part is not evaluated
     2. hence the code reduces to `:class => [@item.type]`
   - when `true`

     1. `&&` returns the second part of the expression. In this case the array `[:sort, @sortdir]`
     2. HAML automatically flattens the array before rendering thus it's equivalent to `:class => [@item.type, :sort, @sortdir]`

Comment: I'd add that while technically working code, this is pretty tricky to read. Might be better to move it to a helper and give it a more descriptive name e.g. sort_order_class

Comment: To clarify, flattening of arrays could be separated by spaces or underscores. Spaces when it's a `class` type and underscores when it's an `id` type that's being flattened.

Answer (score 1):

```
[@item.type, @item == @sortcol && [:sort, @sortdir]]
=>
# if @item.type is blank, so class is still empty
# if @item.type is "numeric" class is "numeric"
class = @item.type

# if @item equal @sortcol
# class will append "sort" and @sortdir if it is not empty.
if @item == @sortcol
  class += "sort"
  class += @sortdir
end
```

This construction `@item == @sortcol && [:sort, @sortdir]` will return [:sort, @sortdir] only if `@item == @sortcol` is true

Comment: Ok, I get it. The output of `[:sort, @sortdir]` is being interpreted in haml as a `class` so it will append `:sort` (as a literal), followed by a space, then the `@sortdir` (as a variable). This is how we end up with `sort ascending` or `sort descending`. Thanks for helping me understand this.